# bootstrap styling not putting the div in rows

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap in my angular application. I have it in my Index.html like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

I also have this in my Package.json

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

still, when I have this code below in  my application then each column goes in different row rather than same row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the screen shot of what I am getting in my application:

[image]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how many rows you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to `styles.css` instead of link tag in index.html file  (**IMPORTANT**)

Also in `styles` section in `angular.json` you need defined your bootstrap.css as

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
]
```

And sure that you install bootstrap 4 for using `col-sm` class.

My sample `angular.json` in project

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your class "col-sm" with "col-sm-4".
you need to supply the **desired number of columns** (tags with appropriate .col-*-* classes)

Comment: I just replaced col-sm" with "col-sm-4" and still getting the same result.

Comment: Please go in browser dev tool and inspect the element and check the bootstrap css class are showing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

install Bootstrap 4 and jQuery from npm

```
$ npm install --save bootstrap jquery
```

open the angular.json file and add the file paths of Bootstrap CSS and JS files as well as jQuery to the styles and scripts arrays under the build target.

```
 "architect": {
  "build": {
    [...], 
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css", 
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
    },
```

If you need three rows use `<div class="col-sm-4">` instead of `<div class="col-sm">`

if you need custom rows refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp).